# uiview animated into right to left(RTL) using swift4

Tags: ios, swift3, uiviewanimation

I need to animated a UIView. the animation direction like Right to left. (RTL) I use a left to right (LTR) animation code is given below
(LTR) Code:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.25, options: UIViewAnimationOptions(),
    animations: { () -> Void in
        self.viewSideMenuHolder.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0,width: self.view.frame.size.width ,height: self.view.frame.size.height)
    },
    completion: { (finished: Bool) -> Void in
        self.viewSideMenuHolder.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
    })
}
```

I need to change a UIView animated direction is (RTL) any one help me.

Comment: Change x from 0 to -view.frameWidth. But you should use Translate animation using CGAffine or change constraints.

Comment: Do your views have AutoLayout constraints? Show the output of `print(self.viewSideMenuHolder.constraints)`

Comment: Hi Sharad Chauhan, I use x position as -view.frameWidth but is not working for me.

Comment: Hi Fogmeister, I use auto scaling for a UIView. Not set a constraints

Comment: Hi Sharad Chauhan, Can you please give a sample code for me.

Comment: Considering the view x position as 280, and trying to move it to left you can try this snippet 

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.slideVW.frame.origin.x = 0
        }) { (Completed) in

        }

Comment: @mouni I didn't ask that :D I asked what the output of `print(self.viewSideMenuHolder.constraints)` was :D

Comment: @Fogmeister I get print(self.viewSideMenuHolder.constraints) is empty array ie., []

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the Solution.  Solution is..

```
       UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.25, options: UIViewAnimationOptions(), animations: { () -> Void in
            self.viewSideMenuHolder.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.size.width, y: 0,width: self.view.frame.size.width ,height: self.view.frame.size.height)
        }, completion: { (finished: Bool) -> Void in
            self.viewSideMenuHolder.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        })
```